# Framework for handling serialization in "key:value;key:value;key:value;key:value;" format

Tags: c#, modular-design

Of course it's easy to write the code to deserialize from this format. I've already done it, but I don't like.

The [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states that I should have a generic class that worries only about this kind of serialization. And the task is generic enough to be coped by a framework.

Comment: Would `value` contain semicolons or linebreaks or such? If so, how would the syntax tell the semicolon that is part of `value` apart from the semicolon that separates one `key:value` from another?

Comment: no, both key and value are numbers.

Comment: So isn't this then just splitting on semicolons and splitting each of those on colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you converted it to a JSON string like (which should be easy)

```
var jsonArray = “[{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}]”;
```

then you could easily deserialize it with Json.NET into whatever you want and Json.NET takes care of converting the values to the right types for you:

```
MyType1[] result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyType1[]>(jsonArray);
MyType2[] result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyType2[]>(jsonArray);

public class MyType1 
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class MyType2
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

or even just as a dictionary (I hope I have the syntax correct, I didn't test it):

```
var jsonDic = “{{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}}”;
var result = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonDic);
```

The single responsibility class (just as an example):

```
public class KeyValueParser 
{
    public static TResult ParseKeyValueString<TResult>(string keyValueString)
    {
        keyValueString = ConvertToJson(keyValueString);
        TResul result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(keyValueString);
        return result;
    }

    private static string ConvertToJson(string keyValueString) 
    {
        // convert keyValueString to json
    }   
}
```

usage

```
var jsonDic = “{{'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}, {'key':'value'}}”;
var result = KeyValueParser.ParseKeyValueString<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonDic);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question.

If it is something your program does a lot then move the function to some area that it is easy to get too (or a nuget package if a lot of your systems need it). If it happens in one place in your code put it quite close to that place.

Comment: maybe it would be interesting to speak in chat..